# How to make JQuery modal close button bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Anyone know a neat way to make the jquery-ui modal "close" (X) button bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the rendered html of the modal you can see the classes attached to the elements of the modal dialog. You can overwrite the jquery CSS with your own CSS to target the buttons and apply your own custom styles.

If you need more help you could post the rendered html from your modal and go from there.

Comment: Its done using an image (url in the CSS). I was hoping there might be an option or something like that. I'd have to change the size of the image (but as its all sprites, that would be a nightmare), or create a new one.

Comment: @MarkW: You can create a style with the same name "ui-icon" I think, override the existing `background-image` style with your own image (you don't need to have a sprite) i.e: "background-image: url("../images/youricon.png");" and add `!important`. Or remove the "ui-icon" class with script and add your own class.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the element css:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close { 
    width: 32px !important; 
    height: 32px !important; 
}
```